# Recursion in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm still learning Haskell and I'm doing a few exercises, but I'm in a jam. So I have a function called "novel" which takes 2 Strings and an Int 
(`novel :: (String, String, Int) -> String`) for its arguments. Novel's input/output must look like the following:

```
> novel ("Rowling", "Harry Potter", 1998)
"Harry Potter (Rowling, 1998)"
```

This is my code for my novel function which works as explained above:

```
novel :: (String, String, Int) -> String
novel (author, book, year) = book ++ " (" ++ author ++ ", " ++ (show year) ++ ")"
```

I am trying to write a new function called, "cite" (`cite :: [(String, String, Int)] -> String`). Cite's input/output should look like the following:

```
> cite [("author1", "book1", year1), ("author2", "book2", year2), ("author3", "book3", year3)]
"book1 (author1, year1)
book2 (author2, year2)
book3 (author3, year3)"
```

I am trying to use "novel," recursively, in order to get the desired output, but I am not sure how to go about this.

What I've tried:

```
cite :: [(String, String, Int)] -> String                -- | Listed arguments
cite [] = ""                                             -- | Base Case
cite x:xs = [(novel (author, book, year)), (novel (author, book, year)), (novel (author, book, year))]
```

This is honestly as far as I got. Obviously, it doesn't work, but I am not sure what to do from here.

Comment: Hint: Look at [`map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#map) for ideas.

Comment: Do you want it to return `String` (i.e. `[Char]`) which uses "\n" in between each citation, or do you want to return `[String]`?

Comment: I don't understand how map would help me here. What I understand of map is that it takes a function and a list and you can manipulate items in that list with arithmetic operations.

Comment: @TheCriticalImperitive I'm not returning a list. I'm returning a String. It's returning it the same way that novel is returning it.

Comment: @JoffreyBaratheon `map` can perform any operation to the items of a list, not just arithmetic. A `String` is the same as a list of `Char`s in Haskell. In fact, the type `String` is just a synonym for `[Char]`.

Comment: @DavidYoung You're right, I misspoke and it wouldn't let me edit my comment. The thing is, I found some pdf text that I'm following and I'm on a chapter for recursion and mapping is the next one. It's telling me to do this purely recursively.

Comment: Note that your function would typically be described by a Haskell programmer as taking a tuple (3-tuple to be precise) of two `String`s and an `Int`. A function of type `String -> String -> Int -> String` would be considered to take two `String`s and an `Int`. An SML programmer, however, would agree with your terminology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps this will give you a head start:

```
cite :: [(String, String, Int)] -> String
cite [] = ""
cite (x:xs) = undefined -- put your code that recursively calls cite in here, hint: use ++ and "\n\"
```

The pattern match `(x:xs)` says this, give me the first item in the list `x` and the tail of the list `xs`. It would be the same as writing this:

```
cite xs' = let x = head xs'
               xs = tail xs'
           in  undefined -- your code here
```

Or even

```
cite xs' = undefined -- your code here
    where
        x = head xs'
        xs = tail xs'
```

Hope that helps push you in the right direction.

**EDIT: OP asked for how to do this recursively, below is my original answer:**

You should probably re-write your base case to say `cite [] = ""`. It doesn't really make a difference, but it will help with code readability.

Let's start by putting ":t map novel" into ghci to see what you get:

```
> :t map novel
map novel :: [([Char], [Char], Int)] -> [[Char]]
```

Which we can rewrite as: `map novel :: [(String, String, Int)] -> [String]`

How? Because `map` does a transformation of one type `a` to another type `b` and applies it to every item in a list. The first argument of `map` is any function which takes one argument. Exactly what `novel` does.

But that doesn't give us what you need, we'll end up with a list of Strings instead of a String:

```
> cite [("author1", "book1", year1), ("author2", "book2", year2), ("author3", "book3", year3)]
["book1 (author1, year1)","book2 (author2, year2)","book3 (author3, year3)"]
```

And you would like it to be a single string separated by a newline character "\n". Is there a function that can take a list of strings and concatenate them into one string, but intercalate a separator between them?

First let's describe such a function: `String -> [String] -> String`. Next we chuck it into Hoogle to see what we get: https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=String+-%3E+%5BString%5D+-%3E+String

Ah, that second function `intercalate` sounds like what we need. It doesn't just work on Strings, it works on any list. How would it work? Something like this:

```
> import Data.List (intercalate)
> intercalate "\n" ["List","Of","Strings"]
"List\nOf\nStrings"
```

So now you can combine intercalate and map to get what you are after. I'll leave the definition for `cite` up to you.

EDIT: Completely forgot, there is actually a specialised function for this. If you just search for `[String] -> String` in Hoogle you'll find [`unlines`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#v%3Aunlines)

Comment: I'm trying to do this recursively, though. I found some pdf text that I'm following and I'm on a chapter for recursion and mapping is the next one. It's telling me to do this purely recursively. And it didn't say anything about having to import anything.

Comment: Ah, if you haven't learned about `map` yet then the above would be introducing too much too soon. See my updated answer.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by, "use ++ and "\n\"." I'm supposed to use the novel function in there. I have to use novel in the recursion. I apologize if I wasn't clear. Thank you for taking the time out of your day for this.

Comment: A very common pattern is something like this: recur (x:xs) = x ++ recur xs. So take out the first item, do something to it then call your original function with the rest of the list.

Comment: If you still have trouble I strongly recommend you read the recursion chapter in LYAH : http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion

Comment: I just got done reading it. It looked at common haskell functions (maximum, replicate, take, reverse, repeat, zip, elem) and redid them using recursion, as well as "Haskellifying" my favorite, Quicksort. I understand how to do these examples, but, I won't lie, I'm still frustrated with this problem. I'm still stuck. I feel pretty dumb right now because I feel like the answer is really obvious. Could you possibly give another really good hint?

Comment: That's alright, mental blanks can happen to everyone. If quicksort does, `sortstart ++ x ++ sortend`, and maximum does `max x (maximum xs)` your function will do something similar. What you need is `_ ++ _`. The left side calls `novel` with the head of the list, while the right side recursively calls `cite`. In pseudocode: "use novel on head of the list ++ cite with the rest of the list". This keeps going recursively until "the rest of the list" is [] and you end up with: `novel x1 ++ (novel x2 ++ (novel x3 ++ []))`.

Comment: I'll leave the answer at the end of this comment. If you get really stuck take a look. It can be pretty frustrating when you just draw a blank and you just want to move on, so if you reach that point the answer is..................: `cite (x:xs) = novel x ++ "\n" ++ cite xs`

Answer (score 1):

There's a reasonably simple way of doing this.

First, map `novel` to each element of the given list, then use `Data.List.intersperse` to fill the gaps with newlines. This is my implementation:

```
import Data.List (intersperse)

cite :: [(String, String, Int)] -> String
cite bs = intersperse '\n' (map novel bs)
```

Or, in a more elegant points-free style:

```
cite = intersperse '\n' . map novel
```

One could also write a nice, efficient recursive function:

```
cite []     = ""
cite [x]    = novel x
cite (x:xs) = novel x ++ '\n' : cite xs
```

In future problems such as this, keep in mind functions such as `map` and `foldr` - these are two of the most integral parts of Haskell and functional programming. Also, your pattern matches need to be enclosed in parentheses.